# Add class to every nth element when i select date

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How i can add class to every date under selected day.

Lets say i click on Thursday and all dates under Thursday have some class.

I have service where you can chose frequency, weekly, 2 weeks, 4 weeks, and when user click on some date add select frequency the dates are highlighted on the calendar.

I have try to add css to every nth child from ui-state-default but this is not working.

````
```
    $('#cookdate').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            altField: '#selectedDatecook',
            minDate: 2,
            maxPicks: 20,
            onSelect: function (date) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var day = date.getUTCDay();

            },
    });
````

Comment: The option `maxPicks` is not a part of jQuery UI Datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a combination of `onSelect` and `beforeShowDate`. For example:

```js
$(function() {
  var selected, final;
  var days = 7;
  $('#cookdate').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: 2,
    onSelect: function(dStr, obj) {
      selected = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", dStr);
      final = new Date(selected);
      final.setDate(selected.getDate() + days);
      $("#selectdate").val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", final));
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
      $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
      if (dt > selected && dt <= final) {
        return [true, "highlighted"];
      } else {
        return [true, ""];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td.highlighted, td.highlighted a.ui-state-default {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Cook Date: <input type="text" id="cookdate"> Select Date: <input type="text" id="selectdate"></p>
```

You can change `days` to be any number of days you want. `beforeShowDays` will then look for the matching dates and add a class to them, `highlighted`.